# Getting global normal from hitTest.face.normal

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am doing a hitTest to create a section plane on a face normal. To get the global normal I have to do some reworking of the `hitTest.face.normal`. It seems to *almost* work, but my result seems to be slightly off from the actual normal, so I am thinking I am doing something wrong:

```
const normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3().getNormalMatrix( this.hitTest.object.matrixWorld );
const normal = this.hitTest.face.normal.clone().applyMatrix3( normalMatrix )

this.SectionExtension.tool.setSectionPlane(normal, this.hitTest.point)
```

[As seen on the picture, my ending cut plane is slightly off the actual plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpIwn.png)

Can anyone see what might be off in that way of getting the plane, or do anyone have a better way of finding the global normal?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please try it with this code instead: `const normal = this.hitTest.face.normal.clone();` and then `normal.transformDirection( this.hitTest.object.matrixWorld );`?

Comment: Same result.. Have been testing a bit more - if faces ar fairly simple and normal close to a clean X/Y/Z vector then I do not have any issue. Could it be a tolerance issue?
I am not aware of tolerance of autodesk-forge, but I can see that face normals have a fair bit decimal points - so I guess a rounding of some sort could make my section plane slightly off like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you share more details on what the face normal should be? Here is the code snippet how the viewer's context menu `Section Plane` creates the section plane based on the face hit point. It might help.

```
const selected = viewer.getSelection();
const intersection = viewer.impl.hitTest(status.canvasX, status.canvasY, false, selected);

// Ensure that the selected object is the on that recieved the context click.
if (intersection && intersection.face && selected.indexOf(intersection.dbId) !== -1) {
    sectionExtension.tool.setSectionPlane(section, intersection.face.normal, intersection.point);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I can figure out exactly what the normal is suppose to be, I can just see on the result (picture attached in the original post) is slightly off.
Could it be a tolerance issue with the normal?
I see the context menu uses the 'viewer.impl.hitTest' instead of just 'viewer.hitTest' I can check and make sure this is not giving me another result.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone should be interested, then i found a solution to my problem
For some reason, when running

```
const currentFragId = this.hitTest.fragId;
const renderProxy = this.viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(this.viewer.model,currentFragId);
```

Before using the normal helped me to get the correct normal. I do not use the 'renderProxy' for anything - but i assume that it helps the viewer in some way. Anyway - this works for me!