# crop particular room/area from the forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are using forge viewer(v7) in our web application.

Our requirement is to crop particular room/area from the forge viewer. For example, if we have shown a house model in the forge viewer then if a user select a **kitchen**(from menu or navbar) then the viewer should show only **kitchen area** (including all its objects like cabinets, burner, fridge, sink etc.) and all other objects/sections should be hidden. Similarly for **bedrooms, baths etc**. It will be just for viewing purpose at run time and not for any automation.

Does any help that how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **SectionExtension** - mentioned here:
[Create a section plane leaning against one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654483/create-a-section-plane-leaning-against-one-object)

Documented here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/SectionExtension/

This also has a function called **setSectionBox(box)** which might be best for what you want.
If you can figure out the extents of the room then you could pass those values to it.

Here is a blog post on getting room related information extracted to **SVF**:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces

The other option would be to find all the objects inside the given room and hide everything else. If there is a property for each object that specifies which room they are in, then you could do it based on that using Viewer.**search**()